# staticなオブジェクトをSWIG, JNIでreturnするにはどうすればよいでしょうか

Tags: java, c++, jni

以下のコードをSWIG3を使用してclass Foo を Javaで使用できるようにしたいとしています。
元のC++コードは以下のようになっています。
C++側のコードは変更することはできないとします。

```
class Foo {
 public:
   static Foo* getFoo(return &_Foo;}
   /* some method */
 };
 static Foo _Foo;
```

これをJavaで

```
 Foo _foo = Foo.getFoo();
```

とします。
SWIG3はそのまま_Fooをreturnするコードを出力しますが、
にしてもclass FooはJavaのObjectから継承されていないので
Exceptionになります。

```
 java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved.
```

ではSWIGにたよらず自力でJNIを作成するとしても
すでにstaticなオブジェクトがあるわけですから、JNIEnv：：NewObject（）で新規オブジェクトを
つくることもできません。
staticですからガーベジコレクション時の挙動も謎です。

どのようにしてstaticオブジェクトを返せば良いのでしょうか？
やはり、不可能なのでしょうか。

Comment: 全てJNIで書いてしまえば解決できる問題に思えますが、SWIGを基本として`Foo::getFoo()`だけJNIでケアしたいという質問でしょうか？

Comment: 可能であればSWIGを基本としたいです。すべてJNIはキツイです。

Comment: ですが、参考までにJNIで解決する方法を回答していただけますと助かります。

Comment: 「Javaで使用できるようにしたい」の箇所をもう少し詳細化・具体化できますか？シングルトンインスタンスを取得(`getFoo`)し、`Foo`クラスのpublicメンバ関数を呼び出したいという意味ですか？C++のクラスオブジェクトをJavaの世界から直接扱うことは出来ないため、両者の"対応付け"を行うコードをJNIで書くことになります。C++側がシングルトンなのであれば、Java側にもシングルトン的な動きをするラッパーを用意するのが素直な（≒力技）実装です。

Comment: 「シングルトンインスタンスを取得(getFoo)し、Fooクラスのpubli‌​cメンバ関数を呼び出したいという意味ですか」です。ただし、Fooクラスの実装はC++側にありこれをJavaから使用したいという意味です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> C++のクラスオブジェクトをJavaの世界から直接扱うことは出来ないため、両者の"対応付け"を行うコードをJNIで書く‌​ことになります。C++側がシングルトンなのであれば、Java側にもシングルトン的な動きをするラッパーを用意するのが素直な（≒力技）実装です。

上記をそのまま実装したコードです。（期待されるスマートな解法からは程遠いと思われます...）

```cpp
// C++コード: FooImpl.cpp/h
class Foo {
public:
  static Foo* getFoo() { return &_Foo; }
  int someMethod() { /*...*/ }
};
static Foo _Foo;
```

Java側のラッパークラス`FooWrapper`を用意します。ここでは`native`メソッドを`static`にしています。最終的にはC++側シングルトン・インスタンスのメンバ関数呼び出しを行うため、Java側APIは`static`メソッドにしても意味論上は等価という考え方に基づきます。

```java
// Javaコード: FooWrapper.java
package com.example;

public class FooWrapper {
  public static native int someMethod();
  static { System.loadLibrary("FooWrapper"); }
}
```

上記`FooWrapper.java`を元に、`javah`ツールを用いてC/C++用ヘッダファイル`com_example_FooWrapper.h`を生成します。

```c
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_example_FooWrapper */
// [...]
/*
 * Class:     com_example_FooWrapper
 * Method:    someMethod
 * Signature: ()I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_FooWrapper_someMethod
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);
// [...]
```

JNIブリッジ層では自動生成`com_example_FooWrapper.h`の関数群を実装し、`FooImpl.h`にある本体コードを呼び出します。

```c
// JNIブリッジコード: FooWrapper.cpp
#include "com_example_FooWrapper.h"
#include "FooImpl.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_FooWrapper_someMethod(JNIEnv *, jclass)
{
  return static_cast<jint>(Foo::getFoo()->someMethod());
}
```